# How to update a custom Stateful Widget using Floating Action Button

Tags: flutter

I've recently started using Flutter just for fun, and I'm stuck on adding actual functionality to the code without having everything inside one class.

*Essentially, I'm trying to use a `FloatingActionButton` to increment the value of a `Text` Widget which stores the value of the user's level as an integer, but I don't want to have the whole app as a `StatefulWidget` because only the level is going to be updated. When the button is pressed, the value should increment by 1 and then show the new value on the screen.*

I have the Level `Text` Widget inside a `StatefulWidget` class along with a function to update the level by one and set the state; the `MaterialApp` inside a `StatelessWidget` class; and the main body code inside another `StatelessWidget` class.

If this isn't the best way to do it please do let me know so I can improve for future projects, thanks.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(Start());

/// The Material App
class Start extends StatelessWidget{ 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Home Page"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
          centerTitle: true,
        ),

        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black,),
        ),

        body: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Main Content for the page (body)
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

        children: <Widget>[

          // removed other children so there's less code to scan through for you :)

          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[

                // Text that just says "Level"
                Text(
                  "Level",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 32,
                  ),
                ),

                // space between text and actual level value
                SizedBox(height: 10),

                // Create new level widget
                Level(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Updating level using a Stateful Widget
class Level extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _LevelState();
  }
}

class _LevelState extends State<Level>{
  int level = 0;

  void incrementLevel(){
    setState(() {
      level += 1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Text(
      "$level",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey[900],
        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        fontSize: 28,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually is a weird way of doing it. However, there is various ways of achieving this

To give an example:

You can use KEYs to remotely redraw the child state

If you want an advanced solution that can assist you in bigger projects. You can use state management tecniques. You can find a lot of tutorials in the internet but these are some of them. BLOC, Provider, InheritedWidget.

Basicaly all of them does the same thing. Lifts up the state data so the place of the redrawn widget on the widget tree will not be important.

I strongly encourage you to watch some tutorials starting with the Provider. I hope this helps